# php, file upload to directory with "spaces" in title?

Tags: php

I am using this code when trying to upload a file into a directory:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../'.$acct_id.'/music/'.$playlist.'/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
echo '{"status":"success"}';
exit;
}
```

**It works fine as long as the $playlist variable is a single string (with no spaces)**

But when the variable `$playlist` is something like `"Greatest Hits"` with the space between the two words, the code will not work?

I did try adding the `rawurlencode($playlist)` as suggested by a friend but still no luck:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], '../'.$acct_id.'/music/'.rawurlencode($playlist).'/'.$_FILES['upl']['name'])){
echo '{"status":"success"}';
exit;
}
```

---

I will try to explain a different way.

The problem in the string is with the `$playlist` variable, not the file name being uploaded.

It appears to me that your suggestion places the `"rawurldecode"` on the file name being uploaded.

The files that I am uploading do have spaces and they work fine as long as the `$playlist` has no spaces, so the problem is with the directory title which is being placed inside `$playlist`.

I have tried:

```
- htmlentities($playlist)
- urlencode($playlist)
- urldecode($playlist)
- rawurlencode($playlist)
- rawurldecode($playlist)
```

Does this make sense? Please help....

Comment: Remove space with dash (-) or score (_) as browsers not supported space in URL.

Comment: The users are creating the directory names (such as "Greatest Hits" "Hits of the 1980s" and so on). This is a UX issue and I cannot require the users to make playlist names with no spaces...

Comment: The file names have spaces and they are being uploaded, its just the $playlist string that is causing the problem.

Comment: Don't use `$_FILES['upl']['name']`. It comes from the browser and a hacker might send you a carefully crafted request that could put the uploaded file in whatever directory they want it on your server. It's a big security issue.

Comment: What if two users want to create playlists with the same name? Why not store playlist names in DB and use the record id in the folder name?

Comment: Good point, but that is not the issue I am having at hand. $_FILES['upl']['name'] is working - its the $playlist that needs fixed :-)

Comment: Each user has their own directory so this cannot happen...

Comment: Remember as noted - it works with no spaces, so it is very close, we just need to figure out how to process the $playlist variable . It is very close.

Comment: Regarding the "Don't use $_FILES['upl']['name']" -- the upload file can only be accessed after a user logs into their account. Having said that, is it still vulnerable IYO?

Answer (score 2):

What about changing spaces to dashes?

```
$playlist = str_replace(' ', '-', $playlist);
```

If it's a part of URL, I prefer there small letters, so

```
$playlist = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $playlist));
```

Comment: So when a user creates a new playlist - you are suggesting a replace the spaces (so "Greatest Hits" becomes "Greatest-Hits"). If thats the case, when the user actually displays their list of "Playlists", can I display these back to the original? By some how reversing the process (i.e. replace "-" with spaces). As a UX issue, I can have the directories on the backend titled as you suggest, but they must be displayed more user friendly on the front end.

Comment: Same with the lowercase - I can do that on the backend, but when they are displayed on the frontend, they must be upper and lower.

Comment: @NetTemple: if you need to present the real dir name, save that into database. Simple table with two columns, `name` and `alias`.

Comment: May resort to that - but right now its super clean with no SQL queries. I was hoping to keep it super efficient - thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Panther's suggestion. I had to use the

```
$playlist = str_replace('-', ' ', $playlist);
```

so in effect, when a user creates a new playlist, the spaces are replaced out with dashes (-) AND LIKEWISE when the playlist is displayed on the user side, I do the opposite and replace out the dashes with the spaces so that it displays properly

```
$playlist = str_replace(' ', '-', $playlist);
```

This solved the problem and the upload doesn't have to deal with the dreaded spaces.